# Show GIF image full screen using Fresco library

Tags: android, gif, fresco

I'm using [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) library to show images full screen. How to show animated GIF images full screen using that library? Is there any other optimal solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the dependency for Animated GIF decoding to your Gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.12.1'
```

Then, simply load the image into a `SimpleDraweeView`:

```java
mSimpleDraweeView.setController(Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
        .setOldController(simpleDraweeView.getController())
        .setUri(yourGifUrl)
        .build());
```